# .jar file can't access the files within itself

Tags: java, image, jar, getresource

I'm been stuck for a while trying to load images.
I've been looking everywhere, but most "solutions" such as .getResource, .getResourceAsStream have not been working for me.

Recently I tried looking at the path that the .jar is pulling the file from, and it seems to be working properly

I got the .jar to print to console the path that it was following using the code

```
// (path is \Resources\(image).png)
System.out.println(new File (ImageLoader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
   .getLocation().toURI().getPath() + path));
```

giving me something like C:\path\Desktop\game.jar\Resources\background.png

I opened my .jar file using an archiver and it gave me the same path.
C:\path\Desktop\game.jar\Resources\
and all my images are there.

Loading from my IDE works properly, but not from the .jar. (the issue shouldn't have to do with case sensitivity). when I actually try to load it using

ImageIO.read(new File(ImageLoader.class...), it doesn't work (returns null);

Does this problem have to do with the .jar not being to access the files inside itself because of permission issues or something else? Thanks!

Comment: "Files" don't exist within Jar files. Resources do.

Comment: Hi Eels, Oh okay, I see what you mean. However, I've had some issues using .getResource and .getResourceAsStream.

I tried one of the solutions provided by the response, and I currently have

URL url = new URL("jar:file:\\" + ImageLoader.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath() + "!" + path);
            
InputStream is = url.openStream();
image = ImageIO.read(is);

but it doesn't seem to work. (null pointer)